# Dynamic invocation - java with interface and abstract class

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism

I have this

```
public interface ICool {
   public boolean isCool();
}
```

Now i got this hierarchy:

```
public abstract class AbstractCoolness implements ICool{
   private isCool;

    @Override
    public boolean isCool() {
       return this.isCool;
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class CoolPeople extends AbstractCoolness {
   protected boolean isCool= true;
}
```

and

```
public abstract class UnCoolPeople extends AbstractCoolness {
   protected boolean isCool= false;
}
```

Now I have a lot of classes that inherit from either `UnCoolPeople` or `CoolPeople`.

When I call them with this function:

```
if (person instanceof ICool ) {     
     if (person.isCool()) {
         // do something
     }
}
```

Problem is whenever this `person.isCool()` being invoked it is calling the `abstractCoolness` class and returns `this.isCool` which is alwayes false.

Any ideas why when I use this function on a person that extends from `CoolPeople` I still get `isCool() == false`?

Comment: Polymorphism does not apply to instance variables.

Comment: is_shared ;) yes thanks, what do you mean by not apply to instance variables?

Comment: If you declare a field in a sub type that has the same name as a field in the super type, you are hiding the super type field. Field access is resolved based on the type of the reference the field is accessed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. This code will return the value of `isCool`:

```
public abstract class AbstractCoolness implements ICool{
   private isCool;

    @Override
    public boolean isCool() {
       return this.isCool;
    }
}
```

Whereas this code will simply set a new variable called `isCool` in a subclass and hide the base member that's found in `AbstractCoolness`.

```
public abstract class CoolPeople extends AbstractCoolness {
   protected boolean isCool= true;
}
```

The method `isCool()` will always return the `isCool` variable defined in `AbstractCoolness`, the other won't affect it. Since the [default value of a boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is `false`, it will never return `true`.

You can bypass this by creating a constructor in your baseclass that takes a boolean `isCool` and pass it trough the constructor of a subclass.

A very quick sketch of the solution:

```
abstract class AbstractCoolness {
  private isCool;

  public AbstractCoolness(bool iscool){
     isCool = iscool;
  } 

  public boolean isCool() {
      return this.isCool;
  }
}

class CoolPerson extends AbstractCoolness {
   public CoolPerson() {
     super(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "override" member value.

In your code, `AbstractCoolness.isCool()` return the value of its private member `isCool`, which is set to `false` by default.

You can either set `isCool` in a constructor or override `isCool()` method in your different concrete classes to return expected value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `AbstractCoolness` is really

```
public abstract class AbstractCoolness implements ICool {

    private isCool;

    @Override
    public boolean isCool() { // Not isShared
       return this.isCool;
    }
}
```

In this case `isCool()` returns the content of the `private` variable `isCool`, which is initialized to `false`. If it were `protected` and not hidden (redeclared) by subclasses, it would work as you expect:

```
AbstractCoolness implements ICool {
  protected boolean cool;
  public boolean isCool() { return cool; }
}

CoolPerson extends AbstractCoolness {
  public CoolPerson() { cool = true; }
}
```

Comment: Right! Didn't even know there were a formal distinction in the JLS. Fixed my answer